# jQuery calling function from newly loaded div

Tags: jquery, function, html, load

I have new div I am loading into my main page called "Next". The "Next" div is a button that is on a page called Story.php I am loading it with this code.

```
$('.CoolBox').load('Story.php', function() 
    {
 /// The "Next div" is NOW on display but not recognized by main page that loaded it.
    });
```

But if I try to make the "Next" div call a function or clickable it does not work.

```
$("#Next").click(function() 
    {
/// Run my code. Call a function?

    });
```

I realize there  are two options. Put the code in the page I am loading so the jQuery can see the "Next" div. I did that and it works fine when I load the "Story.php" page alone, but when I load that page into the main page it no longer works.

This same concept I need to apply to functions as well. How can I create functions that call divs that are not yet loaded on to the page?

Would I put the functions in the Story.php that can access the divs on that page or do I put the functions on the main page and somehow "register" the newly loaded divs?

I am thinking I might be able to use something like...

```
document.getElementById("#Next") /// but what is the full code I use?
```

**UPDATE:**
The full code can be seen here on a page called testing.php
http://beaubird.com/testing.php
Click on the first button called STORY. Then watch for a button at bottom called Next. This is also has a div name of "Next". I want the "Next" div to be able to load more of the story and control other elements on the page.

On line #366 is where I call  this code:

```
$('.CoolBox').load('Story.php', function() 
                {
        /// it loads this page http://www.BeauBird.com/Story.php
                // Where the Next div is contained. 
                });
        }
```

Any thoughts? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish you had showed the code which added next. But without seeing it, try this:

```
var nxt = document.createElement("div");
$(nxt).click(function(){ /* code */ };
someNode.appendChild(nxt);
```

**Edit**

Here is an example for event delegation if you wish to go that route: http://jsfiddle.net/k3fvd/

**Specifics**

In the page linked, the delegated code

```
$(".CoolBox").on("click","#Next",function(){
  /* code */
});
```

is working as intended. Perhaps what was unintended is that the `div id="layer2"` is stealing the click event because it is higher on the z-index or element list somehow. I am not entirely sure what is causing this, perhaps it is that all divs are defined as `display:block;` and that is somehow overwriting the `position:absolute;`. A simple workaround for this is to give more specificity to the `position:absolute;` like this:

```
    #layer2  {
position: absolute important!; 
left: 1px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 3;
width: 1246px;
height: 1031px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
background-image: url(sg_jesus_media/layer2.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Note that `position:absolute important!;` has been edited. This should allow your `div id="Next"` element to receive the click event.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - It is a commented version of the creation which is shown... "`//The "Next div" is NOW on display`". Using this method, based on scope, specifics could be added to the click event instead of a generic delegation as the other answers suggest.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau - I have realized what your problem is, please see my last edit for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks sooo much. Ok it works but only when I open firebug. Its strange. I updated the code and you can see what I am talking about. Using firefox.

Comment: I think I figured it out. There is a div called "BeauIntro" and it might be overlaying the others. I removed it and it seems to work. You rock!

Answer (score 3):

You may use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to fix the problem:

```
$(".CoolBox").on("click", "#Next", function() {
    /// Run my code.
});
```

Here we consider `.CoolBox` as a *static parent* element of `#Next`.

Comment: Perhaps you could also add a note for if `#Next` is not going to be nested inside of `.Coolbox`.

Comment: @TravisJ You are free to complete my answer with any appropriate information ;)

Comment: I tried this method but it's not working. Here is full code on this site: http://beaubird.com/testing.php  Click on "Story" to load. Then you will see a Next Button that is a sign... load on page.  View code and see your line of code at #225. It doesn't see the #Next div that was loaded and does not hide when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Need to **delegate the** event iemphasized text

```
$("body").on('click', "#Next" ,function() {

});
```

`"body"` can be replaced with an static ancestor.

Comment: I also tried this method but it's not working. Here is full code on this site: http://beaubird.com/testing.php Click on "Story" to load. Then you will see a Next Button that is a sign at the bottom. View code and see your line of code at #233. It doesn't see the #Next div that was loaded and does not hide when clicked.